# _int_malloc assertion error

Tags: gcc, malloc

I am getting this error with a c++ program

```
malloc.c:4636: _int_malloc: Assertion `victim->fd_nextsize->bk_nextsize == victim' failed.
```

I cannot post the code. so i am only going to ask for pointers not for detailed help. 
Is it something related to realloc? or free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most likely means your program is writing outside the space that it was allocated, and you trampled on some of the control information `malloc()` keeps.  Assume the problem is in your code, and your library is simply telling you, rather than crashing.

Answer (score 1):

malloc.c:**3806**: _int_malloc: Assertion `victim->fd_nextsize->bk_nextsize == victim' failed.

Try to do a "make clean" to remove old object files. I had originally implemented with new-operator then later on reimplemented as normal class member. Then this popped up in my face. Wonder why my build-system didn't catch this one.